# Finding a value using Runge-Kutta 4th order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I'm having trouble comprehending the following question.

> Using Runge-Kutta 4th order method and a step size of 0.1, find the value of y=0.4

$$y\frac{dy}{dx}-y^{2}+x=0, y(0)=2$$

I am stuck in understanding what is supposed to mean by $y = 0.4$. Suppose that I make it $x(2)=0$ so that I am now looking for the value of $x(0.4)=0$. It still doesn't make sense for me since $y$ is initially $2$, unless a negative step size is valid.

What is your understanding of the problem? Should a negative step size be considered? Does the question actually mean $x = 0.4$?

Comment: The value of $y=0.4$ is $0.4$ by definition of the value of a number. It seems really unlikely that this question was intended to be read literally the way it is written. I strongly suspect either a typo or a lapse in thinking.

Answer (score 1):

In the equation you presented, we are looking for a function $y(x)$ satisfying the differential equation and the initial condition $y(0)=2$. I believe there is a typo in the question and you are just being asked to provide an estimate of $y(0.4)$, using RK4. If you were meant yo find a value $x = x^*$ such that $y(x^*)=0.4$, the question would have surely been written in a different way.

Regarding the application of the Runge-Kutta method, you just need to look up the formula use it instead of the "$\cdots$" below
\begin{align*}
y(0) &= 2\\
y(0.1) &\approx y_1 = \cdots\\ 
y(0.2) &\approx y_2 = \cdots\\ 
y(0.3) &\approx y_4 = \cdots\\
y(0.4) &\approx y_4 = \cdots\\  
\end{align*}

Comment: The question doesn't say that. $y=0.4$ is not the same as $y(0.4)$. It's probably a typo, but that should be mentioned for this to be an answer to the question. As it is, the comment under the question currently provides more value than this answer.

Comment: @David I edited the post.